# Rspec and Devise 4.2: ArgumentError in model test that used to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Rails 5 is now out and I am upgrading my basic login/CRUD app to use the new framework, which involved updating Devise to 4.2 as well.  Things were pretty straightforward, except for one `rspec` test that is failing.  I tried stepping through the code with `pry`, but finding the problem was beyond me.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

This is the error:

```
Failures:

1) User email rejects email addresses with improper format
   Failure/Error: expect(user).not_to be_valid

 ArgumentError:
   wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
 # ./spec/models/problem_test_user_spec.rb:13:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/models/problem_test_user_spec.rb:11:in `each'
 # ./spec/models/problem_test_user_spec.rb:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here is the pared-down test:

```
 1  require 'rails_helper'
 2  require 'devise'
 3  
 4  RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
 5    let (:user) { FactoryGirl.create :user }
 6  
 7    describe "email" do
 8      it "rejects email addresses with improper format" do
 9        invalid_addresses = %w[ user@example,com user_at_foo.org user.name@example. ]
10  
11        invalid_addresses.each do |addr|
12          user.email = addr
13          expect(user).not_to be_valid
14        end
15      end
16    end
17  end
```

And here is my model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :validatable

  validates :email, length: { maximum: 254 } # max length per RFC 3696, errata ID 1690
end
```

Here is my factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name      { Faker::Name.name }
    tone_name { "#{Faker::Company.name} Tone" }
    email     { Faker::Internet.email }
    password              SOME_PASSWORD
    password_confirmation SOME_PASSWORD
    admin      false
  end
end
```

One postscript: the app runs fine in my development environment, but it will allow an invalid password of the form `name@example,com` where the rails 4.2 version passes the `rspec` test and catches this invalid password with an error.

Another clue: I learned that Devise changed the default `email_regexp` to a less strict expression in v4.1. My test is actually failing because an email address that used to be identified as illegal now is accepted.  The `ArgumentError` is not in my code.  I believe it is an error either in Devise or in Rspec.  If I put a `binding.pry` in my test, then a simple `#inspect` on my model causes the following:

```
    12:       invalid_addresses.each do |addr|
    13:         user.email = addr
    14:         binding.pry
 => 15:         expect(user).not_to be_valid
    16:       end
    17:     end
    18:   end
    19: end

[1] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::User::Email>)> user.inspect
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
from /Users/tarsa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.2.0/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb:146:in `password_digest'
```

The Devise code does not look to be at fault, I suspect some interaction with ActiveRecord is going on, but I am at the limit of my debugging skills at this point.

I can workaround the problem by configuring Devise to use the 4.0.3 version of `email_regexp`.  If all the password strings are recognized as invalid, then the bug, wherever it is, does not get tickled.

Comment: What's your factory definition?

Comment: Added the factory definition.

Comment: I note your user class is still inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Base`, have you created the new superclass ([see guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#active-record-models-now-inherit-from-applicationrecord-by-default))? User would then inherit as `User < ApplicationRecord`.

Comment: @Huw, thanks!  I missed that in my conversion, but it has no effect. I did discover a potential lead, and also worked around the test problem, but did not find root cause.  I have updated my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not a Rails 5 issue, but turned out to be from my continued use of `password_digest` in my model, which was originally validated with ActiveRecord. When I switched to Devise, I left this attribute in the table. As of Devise 4.2.0, the mechanism by which validation is done was changed to use `serializable_hash` and that is trying to call the vestigal `password_digest` attribute as a method, causing the error.

Removing the field eliminated the problem and the test failed with the proper message.

Thanks to the folks at Devise for the insight into this.

Comment: thank you for writing this solution, it helped me solve my problem

Comment: Excellent.  I appreciate you telling me.  It is always odd answering one's own question and wondering if it ends up being helpful.